# Pass an object only if Auth is available in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Okay so I've got a view composer; that basically pulls a row from my table 'heros'. This then allow's me to obviously use the object $hero>whatever; on a page. The problem is this obviously only works for someone who is logged in.

```
View::composer(array('home'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('herodata', Hero::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)->first());
});
```

As its using the

```
Auth::user()->
```

to find the correct row in the 'heros' table, once the user is no longer logged in it cannot access this. As no one is set to Auth.

So the error when I logout (or anyone no logged in) is this:

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

));


//Authenticated group
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    View::composer(array('home'), function($view)
    {
        $view->with('herodata', Hero::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)->first());
    });
```

How does one go about this?

Note: Still learning, I DID try and search but I found nothing probably because Im not sure how to put my issue into the correct sentance..

EDIT: Included home.blade.php

```
    @extends('layout.main')

@section('content')
    @if(Auth::check())
        <p>Hello, {{{ Auth::user()->username }}}.</p>
            @if($herodata)   
                Your hero:<br> 
                <b>{{ $herodata->hero; }}</b><br>
                <b>Stats:</b> 
                    LvL: {{ $herodata->level }}
                    Exp: {{ $herodata->exp }}
                    HP:  {{ $herodata->hp }}/{{ $herodata->max_hp }}
                    Str: {{ $herodata->str }}


            Atk: {{ $herodata->atk }}
                Def: {{ $herodata->def }}
                Int: {{ $herodata->int }}
                Blk: {{ $herodata->blk }}

            <form action="{{ URL::route('hero-delete') }}" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete"><br>
            </form>
            <form action="{{ URL::route('rest') }}" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" value="Rest">
            </form>
            <form action="{{ URL::route('attack') }}" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" value="Random attack">
            </form>
            <form action="{{ URL::route('hero-died') }}" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" value="Died">
            </form>
        @else
            <form action="{{ URL::route('hero-create') }}" method="POST">
                Hero:<br>
                You do not have a hero, create one!
                <input type="text" name="hero">
                <input type="submit" value="Create hero">

                @if($errors->has('hero'))
                    {{ $errors->first('hero')}}
                @endif

                {{ Form::token()}}
            </form>
        @endif
@else
    <p>You are not signed in.</p>
@endif
```

@stop

Comment: So when they logout - what do you "want" herodata to be? How can you find a hero if they are not logged in?

Comment: Basically, I want it so; if they're logged in to run that request and pull all the data so I can then do another if to see if they have a hero to begin with. If they're not I just want them to go to the homepage.. if that makes sense?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I added home.blade.php if that helps at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the user is logged in before setting the hero data:

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    View::composer(array('home'), function($view)
    {
        $view->with('herodata', Hero::where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)->first());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Knew it was something simple! I had tried doing an if inside the composer; not sure why.. but thank you!